# How to add an external account to have permissions to a specific repository in VSTS Online

Tags: azure-devops

I am struggling with this, a very very simple task in VSTS Online.

Here's what I want to accomplish:
Invite an external MSA account to have full access to *one* specific repository in my VSTS project.
That's all I want to do.

here's what I have done:
1. Created a VSTS Group called "External iOS Developers"
My thinking is that this group should have access to only 1 repository in our Project.

My invite process:
I invite the MSA.

Problem 1.
In the Users tab, I select the invited account and see that I can only choose between these VSTS Groups:

- Custom
- Project Readers
- Project Contributors
- Project Administrators

"Custom" seems to been have selected automatically.

Why can't I select my recently created VSTS group "External iOS Developers" here?

Problem:
- The invited account have access to *all* repositories.

How can I assign this invited user to have the VSTS Group "External iOS Developers" only?

Comment: Do you mean an *account-level* group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invite users, just leave the `Projects` item empty:

[image]

Then go to the VSTS group "External iOS Developers" to add the user:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My workaround was to deny my ext group to the other repositories. Since I can't blank out the "Add to projects" fields after the fact, I can't really test this without having to delete the external account and re-invite? I will accept the answer anyway.